# Creating a wrl/obj model from point cloud

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, vtk

I want to create and display a 3D model with texture. I have the following information :

- a grayscale image, size : NxM
- the depth value at each pixel
- Normal at each pixel

Using this info, how do I go about creating a wrl/obj file model so that I can display the texture and shape together as a 3D model?

Answer (score 0):

The first goal is to convert your data into a vtkPolyData, then it is straightforward to output it as an OBJ.

You have to compute the 3D points. If your data was acquired in a non-projective manner, You can simply make the 'x' and 'y' values of the coordinates proportional to the pixel indices, and the depth value proportional to the grayscale value. If not, you'd need to know the calibration matrix of the camera you used to acquire the image, then shoot rays from the camera center through each pixel, and move along each ray an amount proportional to the the grayscale value to find the (x,y,z) coordinate of the point.

Once you have the 3D points, it is easy to attach the normals and the colors.